# How can i avoid generating the whole call graph after a change in the function?

Tags: java, oop, operating-system, programming-languages, call-graph

Let's say I have a program for which I already have constructed a Call Graph. Now if I change a function or add or remove a function, what are some algorithms I could use to update the call graph to reflect the changes in codebase?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What exactly do you mean by "regenerating the entire graph"?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please let me know if it is still ambiguous.

Comment: You should be using a proper IDE for development so that you get appropriate refactoring tools to automatically update the classes in the call hierarchy with new method arguments etc.